# Error running in iOS libgdx application

Tags: libgdx, robovm

Error log when executing the app in ios simulator device. I'm using iOS8 simulator with libgdx latest build 1.4.1.

```
2014-12-10 13:07:42.902 IOSLauncher[1395:56847] [debug] IOSApplication: iOS version: 8.0
2014-12-10 13:07:42.907 IOSLauncher[1395:56847] [debug] IOSApplication: scale: 2.0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robovm/apple/uikit/UIAcceleration
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSInput.<clinit>(IOSInput.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication$Delegate.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplicationDelegate$ObjCProxy.$cb$application$didFinishLaunchingWithOptions$(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at com.mygdx.game.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's 2022 and the issue is still happening on the default project that gdx-setup creates for iOS. I fixed the problem by changing the following line in build.gradle of the main module:

```
project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        // api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Still happening in 2023, and replacing `api` with `implementation` helps to resolve this issue. Don't forget to `File > Sync Project with Gradle` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Seems like the class was deprecated and removed in RoboVM beta build (see [this](https://github.com/robovm/robovm/tree/master/cocoatouch/src/main/java/org/robovm/apple/uikit) listing on GitHub - UIAcceleration class is not there, hence the `NoClassDefFoundError`).

Seeing LibGDX repo on GitHub, in [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/d01dc27c6bdad8364b022ebf31542ab6f7fdca2f) commit they removed the UIAcceleration imports about a week ago, so I guess we can either use LibGDX nightlies or wait for the next release. Alternatively I guess it'd be possible to write your own IOSApplicaiton.java using LibGDX updated source on [github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-robovm/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosrobovm) and extend the IOSLauncher from that one.

I still have to try that but I guess it should work.

Hope it helps.

--- Edit ---

I didn't notice that the new LibGDX version has already been released on Dec 8 (v 1.5.0). That should fix the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Maybe the cause is different because I am replying in 2021 while this issue is from 2014

Anyway, in my case in the build.gradle file I replaced the
'implementation'
for the
'api'
when importing the libraries causing the issue.
This solved the problem